# Mapping in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, bit-manipulation

Given a 3d numpy array I want to extract the 2 least significant bits of the numbers:

For example, let

```
img = [[[30, 31, 32],
    [33, 34, 35],
    [36, 37, 38],
    [39, 40, 41],
    [42, 43, 44]],

   [[45, 46, 47],
    [48, 49, 50],
    [51, 52, 53],
    [54, 55, 56],
    [57, 58, 59]]]
```

where each pixel [30, 31, 32] or [33, 34, 35] ... and so on, represents the R,G,B value respectively

I want to extract the 2 least significant bits and concatenate those numbers to create a 6 bit number.

For the ([30, 31, 32]) the 2 LSB's would be 10, 11 and 00 respectively.
This would then be concatenated together to make 101100 which is 44 in decimal. The goal is to make a list of numbers for each "pixel" in the given array.

I want to do this for each "pixel" in the array given using numpy operations and without a for loop.

Comment: Why without a for loop? Anything you've tried?

Comment: @0xc0de: for-looping over a NumPy array is really, really slow compared to other ways of working with them.

Comment: I agree. I guess this is some programming exercise and would like if the OP gives it a thought too.

Answer (score 2):

This bit masks out the lower two bits and then shifts each of the triple over and then sums them:

```
img = [[[30, 31, 32],
    [33, 34, 35],
    [36, 37, 38],
    [39, 40, 41],
    [42, 43, 44]],

   [[45, 46, 47],
    [48, 49, 50],
    [51, 52, 53],
    [54, 55, 56],
    [57, 58, 59]]]

import numpy as np

print ((np.array(img) & 0b11) << np.array([4,2,0])).sum(axis=2)
```

Which prints:

```
[[44 27  6 49 44]
 [27  6 49 44 27]]
```

I'm sure it could be done better but this does get the requested result.

Comment: I get `ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds` with this.... also I had to fix a typo.

Comment: Yes, it works with
`print(((np.array(img) & 0b11) << np.array([4,2,0])).sum(axis=2))`. Good job with the bit manipulation.

Comment: Actually my bad, I have `from __future__ import print_function` by default!

Comment: Could generate `np.array([4,2,0])` via `np.arange(3)[::-1] * 2`.

Comment: Or `np.arange(5)[::-2]`.